# Define Parallel Processing Thread Pool Count and Sleep time

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, parallel-processing

I need to update 550 000 records in a table with the JBOSS Server is Starting up. I need to make this update as a backgroundt process with **multiple threads and parallel processing**. Application is Spring, so I can use initializing bean for this.

To perform the parallal processing I am planning to use Java executor framework.

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor=(ThreadPoolExecutor)Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50); G
```

1. How to decide the thread pool count?
   I think this is depends on hardware My hardware. it is 16 GB Ram and Co-i 3 processor.
2. Is it a good practice to Thread.sleep(20);while processing this big update as background.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Spring processing specifically, but your questions seem general enough that I can still provide a possibly inadequate answer.

1. Generally there's a lot of factors that go into how many threads you want. You definitely don't want multiple threads on a core, as that'll slow things down as threads start contending for CPU time instead of working, so probably your core count would be your ceiling, or maybe core count - 1 to allow one core for all other tasks to run on (so in your case maybe 3 or 4 cores, tops, if I remember core counts for i3 processors right). However, in this case I'd guess you're more likely to run into I/O and/or memory/cache bottlenecks, since when those are involved, those are more likely to slow down your program than insufficient parallelization. In addition, the tasks that your threads are doing would affect the number of threads you can use; if you have one thread to pull data in and one thread to dump data back out after processing, it might be possible for those threads to share a core.
2. I'm not sure why this would be a good idea... What use do you see for `Thread.sleep()` while processing? I'd guess it'd actually *slow down* your processing, because all you're doing is putting threads to sleep when they could be working.

In any case, I'd be wary of parallelizing what is likely to be an I/O bound task. You'll definitely need to profile to see where your bottlenecks are, even *before* you start parallelizing, to make sure that multiple cores will actually help you.

If it is the CPU that is adding extra time to complete your task, *then* you can start parallelizing. Even then, be careful about cache issues; try to make sure each thread works on a totally separate chunk of data (e.g. through `ThreadLocal`) so cache/memory issues don't limit any performance increases. One way this could work is by having a reader thread dump data into a `Queue` which the worker threads can then read into a `ThreadLocal` structure, process, etc.

I hope this helped. I'll keep updating as the mistakes I certainly made are pointed out.